# Check or check in (luggage)

Tags: word-choice

What's the **main difference** between "**check**" and "**check in**"

How many bags are you checking?
vs
How many bags are you checking in?

Is this difference related to the AE/BE difference?
Or they're just synonyms?

Comment: I would have said that check in was the most common usage in the UK and plain check sounds American.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either might be used, with no meaningful difference. To "check" as in "I checked a bag"  is used when an object is handed over for storage or transport in return for a receipt or check (sometimes a "claim check") which is later used to claim the object. "Check in" focuses on the process of giving the object to the service and registering it with them. "Check" without "in" may be used for any phase or aspect of the process.  The phrase "Check in" is more often used when a parson is registering for something, such as at a hotel, event, or the like. But for air or train travel, checking in the person and checking the luggage are often parts of the same transaction.

Comment: Thank you so much, David!

Comment: @Александр Салычев. If you think this answer fully satisfies your needs and is a complete response to your question, you may *accept* it. Only one answer may be accepted for each question. Any answer that is helpful may be *upvoted*. Only the asker may accept an answer, but anyone may upvote an answer, and there can be multiple upvoted answers to a question.